# Another logic brain storm: I need fast algorithm to get last values from large List<> according to some condition

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

I have a data structure as follows:

```
public struct StateItem
{
    public DateTime Moment;
    public int SomeValue;

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return Moment.Hour
            + Moment.Minute
            + Moment.Second
            + SomeValue
            ;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Id.Equals(((StateItem)obj).Id);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Moment.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }

}
```

and in another class I continiously collect such items into the List`<StateItem`> _items as that:

```
    public void Add(StateItem item)
    {
            if (!_items.Contains(item))
            {
                _items.Add(item);
            }
    }
```

As time flows items are continionsly collected, so the list whould contain

"2010-11-11 12:33", 1

"2010-11-11 12:33", 2

"2010-11-11 12:33", 1

"2010-11-11 12:33", 5

"2010-11-11 12:32", 5

"2010-11-11 12:32", 4

so the last item is the last time - that's important!

now let's say the end of list is the beginning point, and i need to get N moment frames with M stepOff, e. g.:

- 1 moment frame with 0 stepOff would return all items at moment "2010-11-11 12:33"
- 2 moment frame with 0 stepOff would return all items at moment "2010-11-11 12:33" and at "2010-11-11 12:32"
- 1 moment frame with 1 stepOff would return all items at moment "2010-11-11 12:32"

Any decision is appreciated much!

Here is the solution i found by myself:

```
 public List<StateItem> GetItems(int cnt, int cntOffset)
    {
            var r = new List<StateItem>();

            int i = 0;
            int iOffset = 0;

            int idx = _items.Count - 1;
            DateTime moment = _items[idx].Moment;

            while (i <= cnt)
            {
                if (iOffset != cntOffset)
                {
                    if (!_items[idx].Moment.Equals(moment))
                    {
                        iOffset++;
                        moment = _items[idx].Moment;
                        continue;
                    }
                    moment = _items[idx].Moment;
                    idx--;
                    continue;
                }

                if (_items[idx].Moment.Equals(moment))
                {
                    r.Add(_items[idx]);
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                    moment = _items[idx].Moment;
                    continue;
                }

                moment = _items[idx].Moment;
                idx--;

            }
            r.Sort((item, logItem) => item.SomeValue.CompareTo(logItem.SomeValue));

            return r;

    }
```

Comment: I don't see what you ask for, but it looks like a Queue or PriorityQueue might be a good choice to begin with?

Comment: Can't start bounty, 'cause of lack of points :(

Comment: If it's important that the last item is the last time, then why isn't it?

Comment: I agree with Kdansky, you just need a Queue. Or a Circular buffer (sometimes called a FIFO buffer).

Comment: I don't understand the question; where is the problem at the moment? It is pretty hard to decipher the intent (for example) of `_dates`...

Comment: Queue is not a good idea, because it is not reusable. Suppose i get one dataset from Queue and items are popped out???

Comment: Sorry, Marc, i fixed the code - _dates -> _items

Comment: BTW, `_items.Contains` is not the best idea, as it must be `O(_items.Count)`.

Comment: If Queue is the point, whould you provide some example according to the note that all the collected data should be stored.

Comment: I think you should use the `^` operator (xor) in the Id / GetHashCode, besides, why use Hour + Minute + Second whereas you can use Ticks property of DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some difficulty in understanding your question, but it seems you want to, periodically, take a number of items from the end of an asynchronously populated sequence.

If I am correct, then you would do well to look at the [Rx Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) which allows you to treat an event source as an `IEnumerable` and use Linq upon it.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, but the point is the mechanism itself - fast and simple :)

Comment: @skaeff: what about the mechanism?  What is not fast and simple about Rx?  Could you be a bit clearer in your requirements please.

Answer (score 0):

Have I understood your question right with this method?  Give it your items, frame size and stepOff value and it will give you a window of results grouped by Moment.

```
static IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, StateItem>> Foo(IEnumerable<StateItem> items, int frameSize, int stepOff)
{
    return items.GroupBy(i => i.Moment).OrderByDescending(i => i.Key).Skip(stepOff).Take(frameSize);
}
```

If that gives the right output you could use it as a basis to improve performance, probably by replacing `GroupBy` and `OrderByDescending` with requirements that the input data is presorted.  `Skip` and `Take` are very nifty though.

**Update**

Strangely I was thinking about this over lunch.  Here's an alternative solution based on the `yield` operator which works providing the input list is sorted by `Moment`.

```
static IEnumerable<StateItem> BetterFoo(IEnumerable<StateItem> items, int frameSize, int stepOff)
{
    // Handle empty sequence
    if (!items.Any())
        yield break;

    DateTime currentMoment = items.First().Moment;

    foreach (StateItem item in items)
    {
        // stepOff is how many moments to skip
        if (stepOff == 0)
        {               
            // Return the specified number of distinct moments
            if (currentMoment != item.Moment)
            {
                frameSize--;
                currentMoment = item.Moment;
            }

            if (frameSize == 0)
                // Break when we've returned the specified number of frames
                break;
            else
                // Yield the current item
                yield return item;
        }
        else
        {
            // Skip the specified number of distinct moments
            if (currentMoment != item.Moment)
            {
                stepOff--;
                currentMoment = item.Moment;
            }

            if (stepOff == 0)
                yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is correct, but as i undestood, your code scans all the list and groups it, then orders and then filters. If so, this is not good in perfomance, as the list is huge enough.

Comment: I need to just check the tail of the list